# Multidimensional Array Filtering in VBScript

Tags: vbscript, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to filter a two-dimensional array with VBScript but VBScript's built-in "filter" function only works with single dimensional arrays. I'm using an array of "rs.GetRows()", so is there a simple function that works with two-dimensional arrays?

EDIT: It's not about filtering database records, it's about filtering multidimensional arrays. I know I can filter those records at database level, but that's not what I want. So what I'm looking for is a filter function for multidimensional arrays.

Comment: ADO recordsets have a [`filter`](http://www.w3schools.com/ado/prop_rs_filter.asp) property themselves. could you filter the recordset before returning the rows?

Comment: Can't you perform the filter on the database itself? What can be done on the server, should be done on the server.

Comment: I'm already filtering the database records but I will process that two-dimensional array with another array. I have two queries that are too complicated to be joined, so I need a multidimensional array filter function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Option explicit

' actual function
Public function filter2dArray(a, text)
    Dim i
    For i = ubound(a) to lbound(a) step -1
        If instr(join(a(i), vbTab), text) = 0 Then
            ' no match. switch it with ubound and delete ubound
            a(i) = a(ubound(a))
            ReDim preserve a(ubound(a)-1)
        End If
    Next
    filter2dArray = a
End Function

' test code
Dim b, i
b = array(    array("row1", "monday", "work"), _ 
            array("row2", "tuesday", "work"), _
            array("row3", "wednesday", "free"))

b = filter2dArray(b, "work")

For i = lbound(b) to ubound(b)
    msgbox i & ": " & join(b(i), vbTab)
Next
```

As you requested: A filter function for 2D arrays.
Limitations: it only works on textual 2d arrays and it does not have the Include and Compare switch, but that is not difficult to achieve.

Comment: Hi, I am kind of new to VBScript like I have a very very old project and I have to maintain it for now but does that function even work because it keeps giving me subscript out of range error

Answer (score 0):

If the requirement is you don't change your interim data structure, then looping through the array and discarding elements that don't fit your filter criteria, or adding elements to a new array seems a good bet. I guess the number of records you're dealing with will have a big bearing on if you choose this approach.

An alternative could be to load your subset into an interim table, then do the filter on that. Some code / indication of the data might help inform the best approach.

Hope this helps.